# Internet connection error with wine/game maker studio 2

Tags: networking, wine

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and wine 5.01 and am trying to run game maker studio 2. I was finally able to get the gamemaker software installed but when I try to login to my account, I get an error that the gamemaker program that runs through wine can’t access the internet. Does anyone know any way that I can resolve this and get it to work?